# Plotting multiple logistic regression in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, logistic-regression

I've built this logistic regression model which includes four predictors, optimized from a dataframe that includes ten predictors (I've uploaded the data here http://www.filedropper.com/df).  This is my first time trying to plot a logistic model in R, and I'm not sure how to go about visualizing the results.  Here's my code:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv")

model <- glm(y ~ v1 + v6 + v9 + v3, data = df,
                   family = binomial, maxit = 100)
summary(model)

df$pred_res <- predict(model, df, type = "response")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = v3, y = pred_res)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(colour = "blue"), size = 1)
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to visualize/plot the predicted values of the model?  In general, does anyone have any tips for visualizing a logit model with multiple predictors?  Thank you!

Comment: General questions about data visualizations are off topic for Stack Overflow. That would be a better for for [stats.se]. It's not clear how you would like to plot a model with so many dependents. I supposed one common way is to fix all the non-plotted variables at their mean and then make predictions.

Comment: Check out the [sjplot](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html) package, the `effects` package or other similar packages. They make life simpler.

Comment: Great, thank you both for the input.  I'm new to Stack Overflow and wasn't aware of Cross Validated.